# how to execute ssh comand on .sh file?

Tags: linux, ssh, sh

I trying to create a .sh file that execute things like "pwd" or "ls" command.
My problem its when i execute the .sh file.
Its seems not recognize the tasks
I tried to use  echo 
Example : `echo 'lsApps'` or `echo "lsApps"`
 but  it prints the name of the task instead execute the comand

for example i want to execute a .ssh file that makes a pwd

```
VAR_1=pwd
echo $VAR_1
```

but it prints me pwd instead the **current path** ... 
Any idea?

Comment: Post your script. Show how you're running it. How is `ssh` involved?

Answer (score 0):

`echo` is used to print on the screen ([man page reference](http://linux.die.net/man/1/echo)). If you do `echo 'IsApps'` it will take it as a string and print it. If you want to execute a command you can just do it by doing `IsApps` (acutes not quotes, acute is usually below the escape key). This will execute the command and show the output on the screen. If you want to store the output of the command in a variable, you can do

```
<variable_name>=`IsApps`
```

This will store the output in the variable. Note that there is no space between variable name and the command. Also, those are not quotes but instead acutes. To print the variable on screen you can use echo by doing `echo $<variable_name>`

If you don't want to see the output at all. You can do

```
IsApps > /dev/null
```

this will execute the command but you will not see any stdout on your screen.

As far as ssh is concerned, do `ssh-keygen` and then `ssh-copy-id user@remote_ip` to set ssh keys so that you don't have to enter your password with ssh. Once you have done that, you can use `ssh user@remote_ip` in your shell script.